# Erlide: how to set start module in run configuration?

Tags: eclipse, erlang, erlide

I have problem with setting start module and function in "Run configuration"
I'm doing it that way:
"Run -> Run Configuration" and in "start" section I'm setting
Module: mod,
Function: hello

my code:

```
-module(mod).
-export([hello/0]).
hello()-> io:format("42").
```

Now, when I hit "Run" I would like mod:hello() to be execute automatically, but it doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The code does get executed...**

When you hit "Run", `mod:hello()` does get executed. The thing is, the execution of `mod:hello()` is meant for system initialization, like loading library code and initializing looping states. The side effect of `mod:hello()`, which is the string "42" as stdout will not be reflected in your Eclipse console. To prove my point, we can create some **more explicit  and more persistent side effects**, like creating a file in the file system called `output_file.txt`. Change `mod.erl` to something like this:

```
-module(mod).
-export([hello/0]).

hello() ->
    os:cmd("touch output_file.txt").
```

Hit "Run", and you will find a `output_file.txt` file being created under your `workspace` directory. This is an evidence for the execution of `mod:hello()`.

**To achieve what you want...**

In an Unix shell:

```
$ erlc mod.erl 
$ erl -noshell -s mod hello -s init stop
42
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to execute, there is an alternative to the answer above: the "live expressions". There is a view with this name in the same place as the console, where you can enter an expression and enable it for evaluation every time a module is recompiled.

This works nicely for expression that aren't heavy to evaluate and that are without side effects, can be used as a form of alternative to having a test suite.